# Replicaset in mongo4.4 with docker-compose can't connect

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Python application, working correctly with Mongo 4.2. I'm upgrading now to Mongo 4.4 and things begin to fail due to connectivity issues.

The error I'm seeing in the Mongo logs are

`{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-19T16:39:05.126+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4834700, "ctx":"ReplCoord-0","msg":"isSelf could not connect via connectSocketOnly","attr":{"hostAndPort":"a091242e0c1e:27017","error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"couldn't connect to server a091242e0c1e:27017, connection attempt failed: HostNotFound: Could not find address for a091242e0c1e:27017: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative)"}}}`

My docker-compose is like

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: <image>
  mongo
    image: "mongo4.4"
    env:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: database
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <password>
      MONGO_USERNAME: data_user
      MONGO_PASSWORD: <password>
      MONGO_HOSTNAME: mongo
    command: --auth --oplogSize 32 --quiet --replSet namereplica --logpath /dev/stdout  --keyFile /keys/replica.key
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  volumes:
    - mongodb:/data/db
    - ${MINIKUBE_REPO_PATH}/src/setup/mongo-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I would expect that `hostAndPort":"a091242e0c1e:27017` in the logs
to be one of my Docker containers (Mongo), but it is not.

Any ideas what could be happening here?